# javascript regex replace all occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match and replaces all occurrences of my pattern with the following code but it is not working:
As far as I understand Regex the pattern should be `/string/g`

```
var text = "ldkfglkfdj {example} fdgfdgfdg {example}";

var List = ["{example}", "string"];

function replace(text) {
  for (var key in List) {
    if (text.includes(key)){
      var regexp = new RegExp("/"+key+"/g");
      text = text.replace(regexp, List[key]);
    }
  }
return text;
}
```

Comment: Don't use delimiters `/` when instancing a regex. Should be  `new RegExp( key, "options")`

Comment: Also, if using regex, if the _key_ chars, contain _metachars_, they should be escaped via something like key.replace( `/([\(\)\*\+,\-\.\?\[\\\]\^\{\|\}])/g, "\\\\$1"` )

Comment: `var regexp = new RegExp("/"+key+"/g");` is incorrect, the first parameter should just be the string, the second parameter is the flags you'd like to set. So, `var regexp = new RegExp(key, 'g')`

Comment: @sln not sure why but mine works without escaping with `{` and `}`

Comment: @jotyhista - `{}` are metachar quantifier, range operators. I'm sure that  `example{27}` regex won't match `example{27}` string. But, this I'm sure of. If you need more in-depth advice, start another question about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't include `/` and `/` when making explicit `RegExp` objects. You only use that syntax when making implicit ones: `var reg = /something/g;`
2. The `g` switch, is passed as a second argument to `RegExp` as a
   string.
3. Also, you don't need the `if` test. Just do the replace, if the
   pattern is there, it will be replaced. If not, it won't.
4. `for/in` loops are for looping objects, not `Arrays` and here, you don't need the loop in the first place. Just find `List[0]` and replace with `List[1]`.
5. Lastly, you were replacing the found pattern with the same pattern.

```js
var text = "ldkfglkfdj {findThis} fdgfdgfdg {findThis}";

var List = ["{findThis}", "replaced!"];

function replace(text) {
  var regexp = new RegExp(List[0], "g");
  return text.replace(regexp, List[1]);
}

console.log(replace(text));
```

Comment: that did it ! thank you for additional tips too ! will accept asap

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily *need* to use regex for this. Just split on the search text and join on the replacement text as the following snippet suggests:

```js
var text = "ldkfglkfdj {example} fdgfdgfdg {example}";
var List = ["{example}", "string"];

console.log(text.split(List[0]).join(List[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this alternative, this is assuming your array has the key-value for replacing.

```js
var str = "ldkfglkfdj {example} fdgfdgfdg {example}";

function replace(text) {
  var [regex, string] = ["\{example\}", "Ele"];

  var regexp = new RegExp(regex, "g");
  text = text.replace(regexp, string);
  return text;
}

console.log(replace(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is used with patterns. If only you want to replace all occurrences without interpreting the string as a pattern, you can use this simply function:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (searchValue, replaceValue) {
    var str = this;
    return str.split(searchValue).join(replaceValue);
};
```

You can call it in your code like this:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(searchValue, replaceValue) {
  var str = this;
  return str.split(searchValue).join(replaceValue);
};


var text = "ldkfglkfdj {example} fdgfdgfdg {example}";

var List = ["{example}", "string"];

text = text.replaceAll(List[0], List[1]);

console.log(text);
```